# Can i use the same UI (Xib files) files for different applications in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a basic UI with just two options (Quit and version) in the menu bar. Will i be able to re-use (load the xib file) in another application?.  I don't have the liberty of creating the same interface again, as the other application is not going to be built with xcode. So is there a way to load the xib file that was created for another application?

Comment: just copy and paste the nib into the new project?

Comment: How are you going to build "the other application"?

Comment: I have a clang compiler setup, can i just copy the nib in to new project and make it?